# Definition of Time Series Season

Tags: r, time-series, seasonality, definition

This is a simple question but I cant seem to find a concrete definition.

What is the meaning of a time series "***season***"?

Quoting from [Rob Hyndmans](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/seasonal-periods/) blog on determining the period of a season, "...the “frequency” is the number of observations per season."

Comment: More specifics? Is there a specific passage of text you're referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Certain data have a natural period by the way it is measured. For example, labor statistics in the US are reported once a month, so the `seasonal.periods` in defining a `msts` object is 12. However, it may be less clear with other datasets. To estimate the dominant periodicity, the `forecast` package provides a function `findfrequency` which finds the peak in the spectral density of the time series.

Comment: I apologize for making the question confusing. I'm looking for the definition of "season" in the context of @Rob Hyndman quote.

Comment: @DataTx You should ask him directly.